# background image blurs in firefox3

Tags: css, firefox

When i use image in my html page using background property .IT loks fine in IE but looks blur in firefox. Wat could be the possible solution.
Thanks,

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page or show the HTML code?

Comment: Do you use any pngfix script for transparent pngs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have found the solution for it. This was the bug in ff3 whih was fixed in late august..
to fix this bug we can use...

**image-rendering:optimizeQuality;**
to the background image..
for more info [check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/image-rendering)  ..

Answer (score 3):

Initially answered in 2009. Since then the provided link no longer works (so I removed it)

1. Try pressing ctrl + 0 in FF (to restore default zoom level)
2. There was also a bug in FF3
   See discussion here
   https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=423756
   This is probably no longer relevant in 2015

Comment: the link is not valid